# Creating multiple pivot fields in SQL

Tags: sql, hive

Good morning Stackoverflow community, I am trying to create multiple pivot fields using SQL. Any help is much appreciated.

 What I have:

| id | r_1 | r_2 | r_3 | q_1 | q_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 38 | 9 | 4 | 17 | 31 |
| 2 | 8 | 27 | 38 | 35 | 16 |
| 3 | 37 | 9 | 22 | 14 | 11 |
| 4 | 40 | 21 | 40 | 29 | 45 |
| 5 | 14 | 33 | 2 | 41 | 42 |

What I would like to have:

| id | pv_1 | pv_1 values | pv_2 | pv_2 values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | r_1 | 38 |  |  |
| 1 | r_2 | 9 |  |  |
| 1 | r_3 | 4 |  |  |
| 1 |  |  | q_1 | 17 |
| 1 |  |  | q_2 | 31 |
| 2 | r_1 | 8 |  |  |
| 2 | r_2 | 27 |  |  |
| 2 | r_3 | 38 |  |  |
| 2 |  |  | q_1 | 35 |
| 2 |  |  | q_2 | 16 |
| 3 | r_1 | 37 |  |  |
| 3 | r_2 | 9 |  |  |
| 3 | r_3 | 22 |  |  |
| 3 |  |  | q_1 | 14 |
| 3 |  |  | q_2 | 11 |
| 4 | r_1 | 40 |  |  |
| 4 | r_2 | 21 |  |  |
| 4 | r_3 | 40 |  |  |
| 4 |  |  | q_1 | 29 |
| 4 |  |  | q_2 | 45 |
| 5 | r_1 | 14 |  |  |
| 5 | r_2 | 33 |  |  |
| 5 | r_3 | 2 |  |  |
| 5 |  |  | q_1 | 41 |
| 5 |  |  | q_2 | 42 |

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Remove the other dbms tags.)

Comment: Using sql through hive

Comment: This looks like an unpivot, rather than a pivot. You're turning columns into rows, not the other way round.

Comment: @Larnu, is there a way to unpivot to seperate columns?

Comment: I don't know for [[tag:hive]], @GreggRoll . It was your incorrect tag [[tag:sql-server]] that brought me to this question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 1 'id', 38 'r_1', 9 'r_2', 4 'r_3', 17 'q_1', 31'q_2'
into #sourceData
union select 2,8,27,38,35,16
union select 3,37,9,22,14,11
union select 4,40,21,40,29,45
union select 5,14,33,2,41,42
GO

-- Two joined unpivots
SELECT [id], [pv_1], [pv_1 values], null [pv_2], null [pv_2 values]
FROM  
(
select [id],r_1,    r_2,    r_3
from #sourceData
)as sourceTable
UNPIVOT  
   ([pv_1 values]  FOR [pv_1] IN   
      (r_1, r_2, r_3)  
)AS unpvt
UNION
SELECT [id], null [pv_1], null [pv_1 values], [pv_2], [pv_2 values]
FROM  
(
select [id],q_1,    q_2
from #sourceData
)as sourceTable
UNPIVOT  
   ([pv_2 values]  FOR [pv_2] IN   
      (q_1, q_2)  
)AS unpvt
order by [id], [pv_2], [pv_1]
GO

drop table #sourceData
GO
```

Comment: thank you for the reply Ian but the actual data source has many more rows so selecting by values may not be possible.

Comment: This will work with as many rows as you throw at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query using `LATERAL VIEW`. `LATERAL VIEW` explode function transforms columns into rows (UNPIVOT the table):

```
SELECT t.id, sq1.pv_1, sq1.pv_1_values, null AS pv_2, null AS pv_2_values
FROM t
LATERAL VIEW explode(MAP('r_1', r_1, 'r_2', r_2, 'r_3', r_3)) sq1 AS pv_1, pv_1_values

UNION ALL

SELECT t.id, null, null, sq2.pv_2, sq2.pv_2_values
FROM t
LATERAL VIEW explode(MAP('q_1', q_1, 'q_2', q_2)) sq2 AS pv_2, pv_2_values;
```